# Use confirm dialog before delete keep failing

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I want to add react-admin a confirmation message like 'Do you want to delete item?'.

So I tried to use [`<DeleteButton />` with `undoable={false}`](https://marmelab.com/blog/2019/03/15/react-admin-2-8.html#confirm-dialog-for-non-undoable-delete-buttonshttps://marmelab.com/blog/2019/03/15/react-admin-2-8.html#confirm-dialog-for-non-undoable-delete-buttons) option  and [`<DeleteWithConfirmButton />` component](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Buttons.html#deletewithconfirmbutton).

But both of them keep occur an error like this.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')
>
> at Object.humanize (inflection.js:828:1)
> at DeleteWithConfirmButton (DeleteWithConfirmButton.js:53:1)
> at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803:1) . . .

#### Problem

It looks like `<DeleteWithConfirmButton />`is a problem. (`<DeleteButton undoable={false} />` also call `<DeleteWithConfirmButton />` internally.)

1. Call `<DeleteWithConfirmButton />`.
2. They call `inflection.humanize` inside the `<Confirm .. translateOptions={} ... />`.
3. `inflection.humanize` use `toLowerCase()` method, but `translateOption` dosen't pass proper string(`resources.${resource}.name`).
4. Error occurs.

Is this error occur because there's no `resources.${resource}.name` in my props? How can I fix it?

**My code**

```js
const BottomToolbar = (props: EditActionsProps) => {

  return (
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading
    <Toolbar {...props}>
      <SaveButton style={toolBarStyle} label="member.edit.editButton" />
      <DeleteButton label="member.edit.deleteButton" />
      <DeleteWithConfirmButton />
    </Toolbar>
  );
};
```

```js
export interface EditActionsProps {
    basePath?: string;
    className?: string;
    data?: Record;
    hasCreate?: boolean;
    hasEdit?: boolean;
    hasList?: boolean;
    hasShow?: boolean;
    resource?: string;
}
```

```js
// my props looks like this
record:
    firstSeenAt: t {seconds: 1502878077, nanoseconds: 0}
    groupId: "ldjapon18073hk"
    id: "pQ--------"
    lastSeenAt: t {seconds: 16000000, nanoseconds: 5700000000}
    managerId: "Me------"
    memberName: "xxx"
    totalTrainedTimeInSec: 37.882999999999996
redirect: "list"
resource: "members"
```

This code is `<DeleteWithConfirmButton />` component code.

```js
const {
        basePath,
        classes: classesOverride,
        className,
        confirmTitle = 'ra.message.delete_title',
        confirmContent = 'ra.message.delete_content',
        icon = defaultIcon,
        label = 'ra.action.delete',
        mutationMode,
        onClick,
        record,
        redirect = 'list',
        onSuccess,
        onFailure,
        ...rest
    } = props;
    const translate = useTranslate();
    const classes = useStyles(props);
    const resource = useResourceContext(props);
    const {
        open,
        loading,
        handleDialogOpen,
        handleDialogClose,
        handleDelete,
    } = useDeleteWithConfirmController({
        record,
        redirect,
        basePath,
        mutationMode,
        onClick,
        onSuccess,
        onFailure,
        resource,
    });
return (
        <Fragment>
            <Button
                onClick={handleDialogOpen}
                label={label}
                className={classnames(
                    'ra-delete-button',
                    classes.deleteButton,
                    className
                )}
                key="button"
                {...rest}
            >
                {icon}
            </Button>
            <Confirm
                isOpen={open}
                loading={loading}
                title={confirmTitle}
                content={confirmContent}
                /* Error occur here! */
                translateOptions={{
                    name: translate(`resources.${resource}.forcedCaseName`, {
                        smart_count: 1,
                        _: inflection.humanize(
                            translate(`resources.${resource}.name`, {
                                smart_count: 1,
                                _: inflection.singularize(resource),
                            }),
                            true
                        ),
                    }),
                    id: record.id,
                }}
                onConfirm={handleDelete}
                onClose={handleDialogClose}
            />
        </Fragment>
    );
```

This is `inflection.js`

```js
**/**
   * This function adds humanize support to every String object.
   * @public
   * @function
   * @param {String} str The subject string.
   * @param {Boolean} low_first_letter Default is to capitalize the first letter of the results.(optional)
   *                                 Passing true will lowercase it.
   * @returns {String} Lower case underscored words will be returned in humanized form.
   * @example
   *
   *     var inflection = require( 'inflection' );
   *
   *     inflection.humanize( 'message_properties' ); // === 'Message properties'
   *     inflection.humanize( 'message_properties', true ); // === 'message properties'
   */
    humanize : function ( str, low_first_letter ){
      str = str.toLowerCase(); // Line 828 : Error Occur in here!
      str = str.replace( id_suffix, '' );
      str = str.replace( underbar, ' ' );

      if( !low_first_letter ){
        str = inflector.capitalize( str );
      }

      return str;
    },
**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think because you didn't give props to DeleteWithConfirmButton, so it has error

In your code:

```
const BottomToolbar = (props: EditActionsProps) => {

  return (
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading
    <Toolbar {...props}>
      <SaveButton style={toolBarStyle} label="member.edit.editButton" />
      <DeleteButton label="member.edit.deleteButton" />
      <DeleteWithConfirmButton props={props}/>
      // In here, you need provider prop for DeleteWithConfirmButton component
    </Toolbar>
  );
};
```

Comment: I found a solution. It was version issue. Related to this.
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/7308

Answer (score 0):

#### For future users who struggle with same problem ..

I use `"react-admin": "3.13.4" in my project.

There's no `translateOptions` in `DeleteWithConfirmButton.propTypes` and also there's no default value for `translateOptions`. So I can't pass `translateOptions` directly and there's no default value. That's why my error occur.

Thankfully, this [error fixed](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/7308) in `v4.0.0`. I update my version and `<DeleteWithConfirmButton />` works.